# Set VB6 reference to Microsoft Word 97 (Word 2007 installed)

Tags: vb6, ms-word

I need to use the reference to Microsoft Word 97 in my VB6 development project.  (Its a long story - in a nutshell if I use ref to MSWord97 then I can support Word 97+).

I use Microsoft Word 2007 on my development machine.  Ideally if I could get away with NOT installing Word97, that would be great.

In VB6 I tried to set a reference to C:\Software\Microsoft\Office97Pro\OFFICE\mso97.dll (path to software - not installed) but that didn't work.  I then tried regsvr32 mso97.dll but that gave me the error: mso97.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.

Anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?  Or will I need to install Word 97 on my machine for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you basically want to do as suggested in [Writing Automation clients for multiple Office versions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244167) but ignoring the advice about using late binding.

The type library involved is MSWORD8.OLB, but I can't recall whether there is any legitimate way to obtain it without Word 97 or an Office 97 Edition including Word.  Offhand I'm not sure what the impact of registering this tylepib would have on your Word 2007 installation either, since they may well share many ClassID values.

In the VC++ article [PRB: Automation of Office Using #import Can Fail if Multiple Versions of Office Are Installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301321) Microsoft seems to suggest this can be a viable strategy as long as you reference the proper OLB.  This is probably less of a problem for VB6 than in C++ because VB6 doesn't use the VC++ #import semantics for locating typelibs.  Then again they may be referring to run-time behavior, since the explanation concludes by once more suggesting late binding.

The article [WD: How to Obtain the Word for Windows Type Library](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143434) offers links to the Word 6 and Word 7 typelibs (links may no longer be good) but none for Word 97, which they suggest you obtain by installing Word 97.

In any case it only sounds safe to use the constants, enums, etc. from Word 97 and use late binding for all of your objects.  This "half a loaf" is better than nothing.  You could still do your initial development with early-bound declarations to geet "Intellisense" assistance, then go back and change all of the early-bound object declarations to late-bound `As Object` and replacing `Set X = New TYPE` by the corresponding late-bound `CreateObject()` call, leaving the actual strong typing as a trailing comment.  One could also use conditional compilation `#If/#Else` blocks to make flipping back to early binding easier later.

Since obtaining MSWORD8.OLB legitimately may be impossible today, you might also consider [OFF: "Built-in Constants in Visual Basic for Applications" (WC0993)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112671) which offers a download containing VB .BAS modules defining the constants for many old versions of Word and other Office applications.  The download link works - as of right now at least!

Since named constants are the primary reason for the typelibs (considering that only late binding is truly safe) this might not be a bad compromise.  You can take the .BAS file you need, clean it up (bound to be some warts in there), and even convert it to a custom "Generic Word" TLB containing just those constants and enums with a little effort.  For that matter somebody may already have done this work.  I'd suggest you try a few searches before writing your own "VB .BAS to ODL/IDL" compiler though.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a reference to your project, look for `MS Word x.0 Object Library` where x is the version of MS Word you want to work against.  I believe you can reference a lower version than Word 2007 (version 12.0).  Look for 8.0.